# dependency resolutions in ruby and python

Tags: gradle, npm, dependency-injection, rubygems, pypi

in [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:dependencySubstitution(org.gradle.api.Action)), you can configure dependency substitution rules and in yarn, you can use [Selective](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) dependency resolutions.

what is the equivalence of that for NPM, PyPI, and Rubygems?

Comment: I'd suggest you re-ask this question about each specific package manager that you would to know about. It's unlikely that one person will be able to answer about all three.

Comment: although I tagged the three package managers but yeah that make sense